# Cálculo del aumento en porcentaje entre dos valores en consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

En una tabla mysql donde registro, por un lado un volumen, y por otro lado la fecha y hora en que se ha tomado ese registro... no acierto a hacer una consulta mysql que me diga la variación en % del volumen entre la captura más reciente y la de hace X minutos/horas, por ejemplo:

```
ID    Sujeto  Volumen    Fecha
----  ------  ---------  -------------------
1587  HGT     1651       2018-05-17 09:55:27
1762  HGT     1725       2018-05-17 11:56:54
```

Partiendo de que en la tabla tengo esos datos puedo sacar el volumen más reciente con:

```
select volumen from tabla order by id desc limit 1
```

Y puedo sacar el volumen de hace X minutos con algo como esto:

```
select volumen from tabla where fecha >= 2018-05-17 09:55:00 order by id asc limit 1
```

Lo que no acierto es a juntarlo en una misma consulta mysql que me retorne, directamente, que entre esos valores hay una variación de 4.28% en positivo.

Comment: ¿La comparación sería a través del sujeto (en tu caso, `HGT`)?

Comment: La comparación es entre 2 volúmenes del mismo Sujeto, en este caso HGT sí.

Comment: He redactado una respuesta con una consulta SQL que realiza el trabajo que deseas. Espero que sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Por cierto, parece que has calculado el incremento incorrectamente porque `(1725 - 1651) ÷ (1725 + 1651) = 0,021919`. ¿Cómo has calculado tú ese 4.28%?

Comment: Si 1725 es el 100%, 1651 es el 95,71%, por tanto hubo un cambio de 4,28% no? A ver si estoy yo suspendiendo ahora matemáticas de primero, con lo buena que era yo de jovencita con las mates jajaja

Comment: Eso sería un decremento del último al anterior. Date cuenta que el porcentaje de incremento no es igual que el de decremento (si a un valor le sumas el 21% del IVA no recuperas el valor inicial calculando el 79% del precio con IVA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta que buscas (actualizado con el comentario en el que dices que sólo deseas calcular el incremento en el registro más actual) es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  100 * (Volumen - Volumen_a) / (Volumen + Volumen_a) Subida
FROM (
  SELECT
   *,
   (
     SELECT Volumen
     FROM tabla t_ant
     WHERE
       t_ant.Sujeto = t_act.Sujeto AND t_ant.Id < t_act.Id
     ORDER BY Id DESC
     LIMIT 1
   ) Volumen_a
  FROM tabla t_act
  WHERE Sujeto = 'HGT'
  ORDER BY Fecha DESC
  LIMIT 1
) t
WHERE Volumen_a IS NOT NULL;
```

---

La consulta interior obtiene sólo el último registro del sujeto buscado:

```
SELECT
 *,
 (
   SELECT Volumen
   FROM tabla t_ant
   WHERE
     t_ant.Sujeto = t_act.Sujeto AND t_ant.Id < t_act.Id
   ORDER BY Id DESC
   LIMIT 1
 ) Volumen_a
FROM tabla t_act
WHERE Sujeto = 'HGT'
ORDER BY Fecha DESC
LIMIT 1
```

A cada registro de esta consulta se le agrega el dato obtenido del registro inmediatamente anterior mediante esta consulta anidada:

```
SELECT Volumen
FROM tabla t_ant
WHERE
  t_ant.Sujeto = t_act.Sujeto AND t_ant.Id < t_act.Id
ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

En la consulta principal se calcula el porcentaje de incremento con la típica fórmula de incremento porcentual:

```
100 * (FIN - INI) / (FIN + INI)
```

Con los dos datos de tu ejemplo la salida sería:

```
Id    Sujeto  Volumen  Fecha                Volumen_a  Subida
1762  HGT     1725     2018-05-17 11:56:54  1651       2.1919
```

Por último, `WHERE Volumen_a IS NOT NULL` evita que se muestren los primeros registros, a los que no se les puede calcular el incremento porque no existe un registro anterior.

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en [este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/emDJca6CEXZYmcbaPeaKci/1).

Comment: Hola Oscar.
Antes que nada mil gracias por la consulta, nunca había hecho una consulta tan "compleja" jeje.
El caso es que hace lo que necesito, pero hay un "pero". Si yo no me equivoco, esta consulta mira linea por linea y la compara con la inmediatamente anterior verdad?
Es decir, si tengo 1000 registros para el Sujeto HGT, me devolverá 999 resultados, que son los de comparar cada línea con su anterior.

Mi finalidad (siento si no me expliqué mejor) es que sólo necesito comparar la más reciente, con la primera de hace 1 minuto, la de hace 5 minutos, la de 15, la de 1 hora, 2 horas...

Comment: De modo que puedo saber la variación actual respecto al volumen de ese Sujeto hace 2 horas, y ver cómo ha evolucionado en estas últimas 2 horas en cada rango de tiempo que yo le paso a la consulta en el campo "fecha". No sé si ahora me explico mejor.

Comment: La modificación es tan simple como poner un LIMIT con la consulta interior. Dame unos minutos, que estoy comiendo, y te digo cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Ya lo tienes modificado. Únicamente necesitas un `ORDER BY` para ordenar por fecha y un `LIMIT 1` para quedarte únicamente con el más reciente.

Comment: Ara sí que sí !!! Mil gracias Oscar ;)

Comment: Sólo una consulta más @OscarGarcia.
En el código que hemos dado por bueno, está buscando únicamente el Sujeto que le pasamos en el Where, pero y quiero sacar la variación para todos los sujetos distintos que haya en la base de datos? He probado a cambiar el where por un group by Sujeto... pero la consulta se ha ido a 1000 segundos y la he dejado por inválida XD

Comment: Si abres una nueva pregunta (para no tener que modificar esta respuesta y "ensuciarla") te puedo indicar allí cómo hacerlo

Comment: Voy!! Ayer estaba saliendo ya de la oficina cuando estuvimos mirándolo :)

Comment: He visto tu nueva pregunta pero aún no puedo contestarla. Bastará con cambiar el `LIMIT 1` por un `DISTINCT` y se hará la magia ;)

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia. Siento importunarte de nuevo, pero la verdad es que trasteando la función no he conseguido hacer el Distinct que me comentas. Abrí un huevo hilo pero creo que no pudiste postear nada verdad? :(